# Laravel factory / seeder creating double records specified

Tags: laravel, factory, seeding

I have `Users` and `UserProfiles`.

All `Users` have one and only one `UserProfile`.

My `UserTableSeeder` class is creating 25 records and for each record, outputting a `UserProfile`.

For some reason, I am getting double the records on `Users` and the amount specified on `UserProfile` So 50 `Users` are being inserted and 25 `UserProfiles` are being inserted.

Seed:

```
public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 25)->create()->each(function ($user) {
            $user->profile()->save(factory(App\UserProfile::class)->make());
        });
    }
```

User Class:

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }

}
```

UserFactory:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'username' => $faker->userName(),
        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => now(),
        'password' => '$2y$10$TKh8H1.PfQx37YgCzwiKb.KjNyWgaHb9cbcoQgdIVFlYg7B77UdFm', // secret
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    ];
});
```

UserProfileFactory:

```
$factory->define(UserProfile::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory('App\User'::class)->create()->id,
        'bio' => $faker->paragraph()
    ];
});
```

UserProfile Model:

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

My expected output was 25 users and 25 users table since all users have a profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code

```
$factory->define(UserProfile::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory('App\User'::class)->create()->id,
        'bio' => $faker->paragraph()
    ];
});
```

To

```
$factory->define(UserProfile::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'bio' => $faker->paragraph()
    ];
});
```